Has anyone come up with a good technical term for a ‘selfie’ yet?
I have been wondering how to speak of a ‘selfie’ in a good court of law.
To my mind, ‘photographic self-portrait’ is inadequate - for the word ‘portray’ connotes, to me, some kind of human mediation: namely, human artistic effort.
As for the word ‘selfie’: genealogically this is like a nickname - an adding of an affectionate suffix to an existing name - rather than a name that demonstrates real thought about what the thing is.
The French, I have heard, have the term ‘autophotographie’ for the form, which implies the term ‘autophotograph’ for the ‘selfie’ itself. This is the best term I have found thus far, as autophotograph avoids the implication of a camera taking a picture of itself, without human action, that one would hear in ‘self-photograph’. Has anyone found anything better?

Migrate to https://english.stackexchange.com/

When I see the "Self Checkout" at the grocery store I always say, "Where's the mirror? How can I check myself out?" There's usually a little camera and screen though, but you have to buy stuff to use it.

@Scott Rowe - anything else you would like to say about this?

Words are weird. I think that pretty much sums it up. Now concepts... Way weirder.

@Scott Rowe - ah, I see you are of the old school. Recommend a bit (more?) of Kierkegaard / Nietzsche if you want things to get weirder :)

"Selfie" is a fine term, widely used and understood. It is defined in the Oxford English Dictionary. It has been used in judicial reasons for over a decade.
The fact that it is used, understood, and defined reveals it is not an empty symbol.

@TomW as a counterexample, walkie talkie is the title of the wikipedia article. Same for blog (web-log) or spam (a monty python reference). I think sometimes these names just stick.

@Kaia - Thanks, but I wasn’t implying that Wikipedia article titles for things were authoritative - only that there are better and lesser names for things, depending on the semantic depth of the term used. There is a semantically richer term in circulation for ‘walkie talkie’ and also for ‘blog’ (weblog, which you mentioned). As for spam, that is not a distinct ‘thing’, but rather a particular use of email (something ‘adjectival’ one could say). Thanks for your input  though :) With regards.
